# Rails find_by_name on another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Genders and based on Gender name create category and subcategories.

```
m = Gender.create(:gender => 'masculine')

c = Category.find_by_name("T-shirt", gender: m )
c.subcategories.create(:name => "Necklace" )
```

and so on.

Comment: Whats the question? Incidentally find_by_name is deprecated.

Comment: you can try this `c = Category.where(name: "T-shirt", gender: m.gender ).first`

Comment: the question is how to get a gender and category name to create a subcategory based on the finds

Comment: right, thank  you @amit-sharma

Comment: @margo `find_by_name` is not depreciated. This is a standard misconception. [Rails 4.0 Release Notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations) That being said it cannot be used in this way. Amit has posted the correct way to implement this using `where(...).first`

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting to learn. I was told over a year ago that find_by_attribute methods were deprecated by a number of different people. Is it frowned on?

Comment: So is a different way to do the same! sweet!

Comment: @margo no it just seems to be people misreading the release notes and then propagating the misnomer. The confusion can be somewhat understood since all the other dynamic finders were depreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
m = Gender.create(:gender => 'masculine')

c = Category.where(name: "T-shirt", gender: m.gender ).first

c.subcategories.create(name: "Necklace" )
```

Please note above code will raise an exception if no category found with given condition, so to avoid that you can use following.

```
m = Gender.create(:gender => 'masculine')

c = Category.where(name: "T-shirt", gender: m.gender).try(:first)

unless c.blank?
  c.subcategories.create(name: "Necklace" )
end
```

Answer (score 2):

While the answer of Amit Sharma works I'd suggest have several improvements for it.

**Use the new Hash syntax:**

```
gender = Gender.create!(gender: 'masculine')
```

**Use find_by instead of where/first**

```
category = Category.find_by(gender: gender, name: 'T-Shirt')
```

**Use the bang variants when not checking the return value**

```
category.subcategories.create!(name: 'Necklace')
```

**Use if/present? instead of unless/blank?**

```
if category.present?
  category.subcategories.create!(name: 'Necklace')
end
```

(this is just a matter of taste. But my brain seems to have troubles parsing *unless* expressions:-))

**Use find_or_initialize_by/find_or_create_by!**

If you want to find the category OR create it if it does not exist, use find_or_initialize/find_or_create_by!() so you can avoid the nil check:

```
category = Category.find_or_create_by!(gender: gender, name: 'T-Shirt')
```

So in total i'd write it like:

```
gender = Gender.create!(gender: 'masculine')
category = Category.find_or_create_by!(gender: gender, name: 'T-Shirt')
category.subcategories.create!(name: 'Necklace')
```

Comment: Bang variants will raise which can cause a 500 if the exception is under handled. Not always optimum better to check the return than handle an exception in my opinion.

Comment: engineersmnky: that is why i opt for bang variants when not checking the return value. Of course it is better if you check the return value and react to it.